# What is root node in javascript

Tags: javascript

Why we use root node. In below given function they use root node function. I want to understand this function also what is meaning of '!rootNode'.

```
 function getElementsByClassName(cn, rootNode) {
  if (!rootNode) {
    rootNode = document;
  } 
  for (var r=[], e=rootNode.getElementsByTagName('*'), i=e.length; i--;) {
    if ((' '+e[i].className+' ').indexOf(' '+cn+' ')>-1) {
      r.push(e[i]); 
    }
  }
  return r;  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, `rootNode` is the HTML element from which to start recursively searching the hierarchical [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) tree (which is how the web page is represented in JavaScript) for elements with class name `cn`.

This allows the caller of your function to specify from where they want to search for elements with class name `cn`. If the caller does not specify `rootNode` the function just returns every element in the entire web page with class name `cn`.

The array `r=[]` is initialised as an empty array into which the elements that are found get added (using `push`).

`i--` is used because the `for` loop starts at `i=e.length` - the function goes through the elements returned by `getElementsByTagName` from the end of the array through to the start. The `for` loop evaluates the result of `i--` as a boolean, exitting when `i` hits `-1` (because on this iteration the boolean evaluation will have been done against the falue `0`, because `i--` [post-decrements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators) the value of `i`).

Comment: one more thing in that function why we are using blank array and i-- why not i++

Comment: last thing to know why i-- why not i++

Comment: @RichardEv This decrement decision is also a performance improvement, over otherwise (var i=0; i < rootNode.getElementsByTagName('*').length; i++) , since in the latter case getElementsByTagName will be hit each time. getElementsByTagName has to return the live count and hence will have to preform a DOM count on each iteration then.

Answer (score 1):

`rootNode` in that function is the top level node that you want to look for elements starting from.  `document` would look in the entire document.  `document.body` would look only in the body of the document.  Some other element in the body would look only in the children of that element.

The statement:

```
if (!rootNode) {
```

is checking to see if you passed anything for that parameter and if you didn't or passed `undefined` or `null` or any other falsey value, it is defaulting to the document as the root node.  This allows one to use the function like:

```
var items = getElementsByClassName("foo");
```

and the function will look in the entire document.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, One more thing why we are using blank array in this function and i-- why not i++

Comment: The blank array `r=[]` is just initializing the array where results are going to be accumulated.  I don't know why the loop iterates backwards as that will lead to returning the results in backwards document order.  It also looks to me to be faulty where it will miss the first item returned by `getElementsByTagName()`.

Answer (score 1):

`if (!rootNode)` in your code checks if `rootNode` is `null` or `undefined`.

The method seems to search a DOM subTree represented by rootNode for nodes with class matching  `cn`. If rootNode is not passed-in (`getElementsByClassName('cn')`) or null, then the method searches the whole HTML document for possible matches.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't give a rootNode as parameter, the whole document will be searched. Otherwise all descending nodes from the given rootnode will be searched.